# Collision exceptions when objects collide

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, chipmunk

I'm developing a functionality that some objects need to collide, i works ok in many cases, but time to time i recibe an internal exception.
I'm sure i'm not applying a good practice here, that is the case i guess..
I do the following:

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair sCMalletPlayerTwo:(CCNode *)PlayerTwoMallet sCPuck:(CCNode *)pack
{
    [pack.physicsBody         applyImpulse:CGPointMake(pack.physicsBody.velocity.x, pack.physicsBody.velocity.y)];

    return YES;
}
```

There are static and dynamic body colliding. the delegate get's invoked ok...
But some time i get this exception:

> Aborting due to Chipmunk error: Internal Error: Dangling contact graph
>   pointers detected. (B)    Failed condition: cpArbiterThreadForBody(arb,
>   body)->prev == NULL

Can someone help me on this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you posted is most likely not the culprit. Are you using threads in any way (ie GCD, performSelectorInBackground, etc)? You should post this on http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org as well to get feedback from the devs. And mention the version of cocos2d you are using (it's printed in the log respectively in cocos2d.h).

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'm not using any thread... maybe need to do something like that... wait until a collision ends to start the next.. maybe call in a call backBlock?

Comment: I do think there's a concrete problem, either caused by your code or through circumstances triggering a bug in Chipmunk. But it may be caused by other collision callbacks (if you have more than one), in any case it can't be just the code in that particular method you posted. On the cocos2d forum you could ask for when this assertion can occur which may give you pointers as to what code actually causes the issue.